# how to draw a view with zigzag at the top in android custom view canva

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I'm too fresh in android custom views and trying to create a view like this (**the white view only**)
[image]

but the view with me looks like this[image]

here is my code:

```
class TestCurvedPathView @JvmOverloads
    constructor(
    private val ctx: Context,
    private val attributeSet: AttributeSet? = null,
    private val defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : View(ctx, attributeSet, defStyleAttr) {

    var path = Path()
    var pathPaint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG).apply {
        color = Color.parseColor("#892cdc")
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        drawCurvedPath(canvas)
    }

    private fun drawCurvedPath(canvas: Canvas?) {

        path.moveTo(0f * width, 0.2f * height)
        path.quadTo(0.4f * width, 0.1f * height, 0.6f * width, 0.4f * height)
        path.quadTo(0.8f * width, 0.5f * height, 1f * width, 0.4f * height)
        path.lineTo(1f * width, 1f * height)
        path.lineTo(0f * width, 1f * height)

        canvas?.drawPath(path, pathPaint)

    }
}
```

It does not go smoothly in the middle, any ideas?

thanks for helping

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22763632/6287910) can help.

Comment: This is is a bezier curve you can create using two cubic curves (`path.cubicTo`) where the second control point of the first curve and first control point of the second curve are in a straight line with the common endpoint/startpoint so the curves will have the same slope at that point. You can look up the math to figure out how to pick the control points. But it would probably be easiest to draw this in a vector program and import the SVG as a vector drawable to draw directly.