# Android - How to draw closed curve

Tags: android

Im drawing closed curve in android. I following by post in [Construct spline with android.graphics.Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22763632/construct-spline-with-android-graphics-path).
But last point and first point not ok. See image

I dont now close shape. Please help me

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQWQt.png)